# Unable to load bootstrap panels nested within nav tabs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I dont know what is wrong with my code but for some reason I am unable to load the bootstrap panels styling within one of my tab sections. I managed to make it load correctly in my "announcements" tab section, however the panels dont appear correctly in my "notifcations" section even though I applied the exact same code to it. Here is a link to the website im developing:

https://mpw-web.herokuapp.com/

and here is the code for that page:

```html
<h3>Announcements & Notifications</h3>


<div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Announcements</strong></a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Notifications</strong><span class="badge">3</span></a></li>




  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
     <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Public Holiday<span class="label label-warning">New!</span></h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>There will be a public holiday on 5/5/2015</p>
     <h6> Date: 4/15/2015</h6>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Project X Delayed</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Project x has been delayed due to (place reason here)</p>
      <h6> Date: 4/8/2015</h6>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Project X new Phase</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Project has moved to phase 3 after successful review of phase 2.</p>
      <h6> Date: 4/2/2015</h6>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">New Workshops!</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>The following new workshops have been introduces: <br><br>
       - Basic Photoshop  (7/6/2015) <br>
       - Interior Design 101  (6/6/2015) <br>
       - Awsome Workshop no.300  (25/8/2015) <br><br>
       if interested, please contact employee x for registration
      </p>
      <h6> Date: 3/34/2015</h6>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Public Holiday</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>There will be a public holiday on 5/5/2015</p>
      <h6> Date: 4/15/2015</h6>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Project X Delayed</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Project x has been delayed due to (place reason here)</p>
      <h6> Date: 4/8/2015</h6>
     </div>

     <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Project X new Phase</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="panel-body">
      <p>Project has moved to phase 3 after successful review of phase 2</p>
      <h6> Date: 4/2/2015</h6>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
     <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">Vacation Replacement Request</h4>
    <div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <p>Employee X has requested you as his/her replacement while on vacation from <strong>12/7/2015</strong> to <strong>12/8/2015</strong></p>
     <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Accept</button></a>
     <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline</button></a>
     <h6> Date: 4/15/2015</h6>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">New Project Invitation</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <p>You have been invited by employee Y to join Project X</p>
     <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Accept</button></a>
     <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline</button></a>
     <h6> Date: 4/8/2015</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
     <h4 class="panel-title">Job Request</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <p>You have been requested to perform the following task:<br><br>
      - <strong>Task:</strong> Site Visit<br>
      - <strong>Project:</strong> X<br>
      - <strong>Location:</strong> Kuwait City<br>
      - <strong>Time:</strong> 10 am<br><br>
      Please contact <a href="#">Employee X</a> for further information.
     </p>
     <h6> Date: 4/2/2015</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: The issue is with your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with bootstrap. You have an issue with your HTML structure. You have opened / closed div(s) improperly.
Following is a proper HTML structure for tabpanel:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="profile">
    <div class="panel panel-info">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Vacation Replacement Request</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Employee X has requested you as his/her replacement while on vacation from <strong>12/7/2015</strong> to <strong>12/8/2015</strong></p>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Accept</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline</button></a>
            <h6> Date: 4/15/2015</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">New Project Invitation</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>You have been invited by employee Y to join Project X</p>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Accept</button></a>
            <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline</button></a>
            <h6> Date: 4/8/2015</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">Job Request</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>You have been requested to perform the following task:<br><br>
                - <strong>Task:</strong>    Site Visit<br>
                - <strong>Project:</strong> X<br>
                - <strong>Location:</strong>    Kuwait City<br>
                - <strong>Time:</strong>    10 am<br><br>
                Please contact <a href="#">Employee X</a> for further information.
            </p>
            <h6> Date: 4/2/2015</h6>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO - Your Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ms32ke8/) 
[**DEMO - Updated Code**](http://jsfiddle.net/g3swL9r5/)

Comment: I just found the mistake in my code, as you said I merely didnt close one of div tags correctly. Thanks for the help! :)